# How to make a phone call with data from the usb or audiojack

Tags: android, ios, iphone, arduino, phone-call

I was wondering if it is possible to be able to upload data through the usb or audiojack of a phone so that it can then make a call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however you would need to create a custom application on the phone that has access to the cellular module. The application would scan the audio jack for commands sent by the arduino and then a built in interpretor would convert the input into data that the phone can understand.

```
Arduino <--> Custom Application <--> Phone <--> Network
```

---

(although I would recommend using an arduino compatible cellular module to keep things simple)

---

Alternatively you could use a BLE shield and just have a Bluetooth interface (which would free up the usb/headphone ports on the phone at the expense of purchasing a BLE shield)